# Rename 'refinsh' tag to refinish?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

Not sure if this belongs here but it seems like the 'refinsh' tag is a misspelling of 'refinish', and should be renamed somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch!

I created a new tag, [refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refinishing) (because we have the other tags [basement-refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basement-refinishing) and [hardwood-refinishing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardwood-refinishing) this seemed like the logical choice for a name), and merged the typo tag [refinsh](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refinsh) into it, without creating a synonym.

End result: all the questions that had the bad tag on them now have the new tag instead.